# Getting error in vite ,vue2 project with vuetify [[vuetify:import] (0 , vue_1.camelize) is not a function}

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vite

I am using vue 2 and is trying to migrate to vite. But vuetify is causing some error as shown below

```
[vuetify:import] (0 , vue_1.camelize) is not a function
file: /home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/src/App.vue
error during build:
TypeError: (0 , vue_1.camelize) is not a function
    at /home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/node_modules/@vuetify/loader-shared/dist/imports/parseTemplate.js:14:56
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)
    at createSet (/home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/node_modules/@vuetify/loader-shared/dist/imports/parseTemplate.js:12:26)
    at parseTemplate (/home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/node_modules/@vuetify/loader-shared/dist/imports/parseTemplate.js:6:24)
    at getImports (/home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/node_modules/@vuetify/loader-shared/dist/imports/getImports.js:7:74)
    at generateImports (/home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/node_modules/@vuetify/loader-shared/dist/imports/generateImports.js:6:77)
    at Object.transform (/home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/node_modules/vite-plugin-vuetify/dist/importPlugin.js:26:87)
    at file:///home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:22748:40
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "vapp4",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "7.0.96",

    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.4",
    "vue": "2.6.14",
    "vue-cookie": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-router": "3.5.1",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.0",
    "vuex": "3.6.2",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.3",
    "vite": "^3.1.9",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.0-alpha.12"
  }
}
```

I have tried to install camelize but did not solve my problem.

I have tried upgrading to vue 3.
None of this worked

getting error

```
[vuetify:import] (0 , vue_1.camelize) is not a function
file: /home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/src/App.vue
error during build:
TypeError: (0 , vue_1.camelize) is not a function
    at /home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/node_modules/@vuetify/loader-shared/dist/imports/parseTemplate.js:14:56
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)
    at createSet (/home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/node_modules/@vuetify/loader-shared/dist/imports/parseTemplate.js:12:26)
    at parseTemplate (/home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/node_modules/@vuetify/loader-shared/dist/imports/parseTemplate.js:6:24)
    at getImports (/home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/node_modules/@vuetify/loader-shared/dist/imports/getImports.js:7:74)
    at generateImports (/home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/node_modules/@vuetify/loader-shared/dist/imports/generateImports.js:6:77)
    at Object.transform (/home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/node_modules/vite-plugin-vuetify/dist/importPlugin.js:26:87)
    at file:///home/vivek/findependence/findiserver/vapp4/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:22748:40
```

Answer (score 2):

you should be using `vue` 2.7 and `@vitejs/plugin-vue-2`

https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-vue2

for vuetify I'm using `unplugin-vue-components/vite`

```
// vite.config.ts
import vue2 from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2';
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite';
import { VuetifyResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers';

    plugins: [
      vue2(),
      Components({
        // generate `components.d.ts` global declarations
        // https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components#typescript
        dts: true,
        // relative paths to the directory to search for components.
        dirs: ['src/common/components/base'],
        // auto import for directives
        directives: false,
        // resolvers for custom components
        resolvers: [
          // Vuetify
          VuetifyResolver(),
        ],
        // https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components#types-for-global-registered-components
        types: [
          {
            from: 'vue-router',
            names: ['RouterLink', 'RouterView'],
          },
        ],
      }),
    ],
```